# How to ignore case sensitive properties name in WCF service call?

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

Hello I wonder about possibility to call WCF method from client side what would be ignore case sensitive properties names (on client side I am working with JSON with lowercase properties name, but on server side with uppercase). WCF can't map properties in this case.
Is it possible to use some WCF attributes or etc?

```
 public interface IMyWCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool UpdateUser(User user);

}
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class User : ICloneable  
    {
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "login")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Login value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public String Login { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Name` property of the `[DataMember]` attribute to map the property name:

```
[DataContract]
public class User : ICloneable  
{
    [DataMember(Name = "login")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "login")]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Login value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public String Login { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

*Update following comment*: There isn't any knob you can use to enable case-insensitive deserialization on the default serializer used by WCF. There are some options (none ideal), though. You can change the serializer to use JSON.NET (which can be done, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx), but not very easily) and use the serializer settings in that serializer to ignore casing. I think you should also be able to add additional properties (which can be private, except if the application is running in partial trust), to map the additional supported cases; something similar to the code below:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Login { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    private String login { get { return this.Login; } set { this.Login = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    private int id { get { return this.UserId; } set { this.UserId = value; } }
}
```

Comment: yes, but what about case I need to have both variant working with lower and upper case ?

Comment: did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde 4 years later: you can add another property to the object that just wraps the existing property. Then, use the name parameter on DataMember to be the upper/lower case variant you want.