# Are the method names and parameter names case sensitive in a SOAP message

Tags: .net, wcf, asmx

If I were to change the case of a method name and parameters, would this adversely affect clients making use of a asmx or WCF web service?

```
public string getSTRING(int INPUT)
{
    return INPUT.ToString();
}
```

to....

```
public string GetString(int input)
{
    return input.ToString();
}
```

Would clients needed to regenerate their proxy objects to make use of the changed methods?

Comment: What keeps you from trying, or looking up the SOAP specs, preferably both? Also see this question where yours gets answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574621/how-to-ignore-case-sensitive-properties-name-in-wcf-service-call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the parameters names on server side should match (including case) parameter names, defined in operation contracts. As well as method names.

If you need control over it - you can use   `MessageParameterAttribute`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageparameterattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The value of the **parameter names** in the operation signature **are part
>   of the contract and are case sensitive**. Use this attribute when you
>   need to distinguish between the local parameter name and the metadata
>   that describes the operation for client applications.